# Paste data from Recordset

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I want to paste the data in record set to 3 columns in a worksheet.

```
 rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].Security,[Sheet1$].Description,[Sheet1$].ID FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].Number=1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    .Cells.ClearContents
    .Cells(5, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
```

When I use the above code it pastes the data in to sheet 4 starting from 5,1, whereas I want to paste this data in column A, E, H of sheet 4. can anyone throw some light please.

Comment: Not sure if you can paste data from a recordset in a discontinuous range.  You'd probably have to copy it to a temp worksheet and then copy the columns you want or create 3 recordsets and then paste them 1 at a time in the desired columns.

Comment: Loop over the recordset and copy each field value to the relevant column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put constant values into a SELECT statement so:

```
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].Security, '', '', '', [Sheet1$].Description, '', '', [Sheet1$].ID FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].Number=1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

or you can use NULL:

```
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].Security, NULL, NULL, NULL, [Sheet1$].Description, NULL, NULL, [Sheet1$].ID FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].Number=1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

*edit:* this will obliterate everything in columns B:D and F:G which may or may not be an issue for you